# Fullcalendar add tooltip to events

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar

I'm using fullcalendar in my php site. I load events with eventSources, giving it an url redirecting to my php controller, which generates json data. Before the calendar is rendered, I wish every event has a tooltip. To this scope I wrote a javascript function that add the tooltip:

```
 function dailyTooltip(){
   $('.fc-day-grid-event, .fc-time-grid-event').each(function(){
      var content = $(this).data('content');
      $(this).attr('title',''); 
      $(this).tooltip({
       tooltipClass: 'event-tooltip',
       content: content,
      }); 
   });
 }
```

where content is html content. The function runs after calendar rendering.
After the calendar has been rendered, the tooltip is not showing.

To resolve this problem, I tried to add the function to datesRender, and eventRender. datesRender seems to work, but only when I change view (e.g. from timeGrid to dayMonthGrid). eventRender doesn't work.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `Tooltip.js` with `fullcalendar eventRender` for showing tooltips,

```
<script src='https://unpkg.com/tooltip.js/dist/umd/tooltip.min.js'></script>
```

you can use event render function like this:

```
eventRender: function(info) {
        var tooltip = new Tooltip(info.el, {
          title: info.event.extendedProps.description,//you can give data for tooltip
          placement: 'top',
          trigger: 'hover',
          container: 'body'
        });
      },
```

> Check out [Event render Tooltip Fullcalendar demo](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v4/event-tooltip-demo)

Comment: Thank you for answer, but I think the problem is in datesRender/eventRender. I need to execute both to show other objects in the events and they work well. For showing tooltips works only datesRender. I noticed switching from different views (dayGrid->timeGrid) and going back to previous view (dayGrid), I can see the tooltips.

Comment: Please consider updating the answer, since the link to fullcalendar docs is no longer valid .

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but if someone finds this post.
FullCalendar v5 has a hover example.
https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-tooltip-demo

You can also view it in code pen(top right hand corner button)

Make sure to add the two js scripts.
https://unpkg.com/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js
https://unpkg.com/tooltip.js/dist/umd/tooltip.min.js

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31369990)

Answer (score 0):

In fullcalendar.js V5, there is no eventRender. So what I did is everytime I click any button on the calendar header i create their tooltip

```
<script src='https://unpkg.com/tooltip.js/dist/umd/tooltip.min.js'></script>


const calendarControlBtns = Array.from(
  document.querySelectorAll('.fc-header-toolbar button')
);
calendarControlBtns.forEach((singleControlBtn) => {
  singleControlBtn.addEventListener('click', handleNewInterval);
});
const handleNewInterval = (e) => {
  const allEvents = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.fc-timegrid-event'));
  allEvents.forEach((singleEvent) => {
    singleEvent.dataset.toggle = 'tooltip';
    const title = singleEvent.querySelector('.fc-event-title').innerHTML;
    singleEvent.dataset.title = title;
  });
  $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
}
```

Comment: just make sure the code snippet is working ;)

Comment: i thought was better to see the js ;)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone using older versions.
I had to use V2 of the calendar and the way I did it was to have a div with a tooltip:

```
<div id="tooltip-span" class="my-tooltip" style="display: none">Hover me</div>
```

with this css:

```
.my-tooltip {
        position: absolute;
        z-index: 9999;
        background: #7F8C8D;
        color: white;
        width: 150px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
        padding: 10px;
        text-align: center;
    }
```

And then just used the eventMouseover and eventMouseout, which can be consulted on:https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/eventMouseover
In this case from V3 to below
And then here are my events:

```
eventMouseover: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
    var tooltipSpan = document.getElementById('tooltip-span');
    tooltipSpan.innerHTML = event.msg;
    var x = jsEvent.originalEvent.clientX + 10; // Adjust positioning as needed
    var y = jsEvent.originalEvent.clientY + 10; // Adjust positioning as needed
    tooltipSpan.style.top = y + 'px';
    tooltipSpan.style.left = x + 'px';
    tooltipSpan.style.display = 'block'; // Show the tooltip
},
eventMouseout: function(event, jsEvent, view) {
    var tooltipSpan = document.getElementById('tooltip-span');
    tooltipSpan.style.display = 'none'; // hide the tooltip
},
```

For me it all works fine, and had to make this workaround since I can't upgrade the calendar version.